# How to show totals of a measure if the dimension is not part of the fact table in OBIEE

Tags: repository, dimension, obiee, measure, calculation

I hope someone has a clue how to solve this issue.

I have two fact tables one with revenue per company, year, catalogue_no and revenue and the other with company, year and customer_base.

I want to combine these measures in an analysis but the catalogue_no is not part of the `customer_base` table.

What I've achieved so far, by setting the right levels in BMM, is that I can put the catalogue_no in the filter criterias and get the result that all figures are shown correctly.

As soon as I place the dimension `catalogue_no` into the selected columns the `customer_base` is only blank.

See the picture for Explanation. [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8VQ9.gif)

Comment: So did it work in the end?

Comment: It works in our case, but I have to agree with you that it could be better by using the levels correctly. The problem is, that the data model has to migrated from SAP BO and to work with OBIEE, but tables must not be changed to provide the same figures as in the original system. But thank you for your suggestions, after migration it would be possible to set up all levels and joins in a better way, as we can change the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the content level for the non-conformed dimension to the "Grand Total" level

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but setting the non-conformed dimensions to "Grand Total" only has the effect, that I can filter with catalogue_no and the fact table with the customer base ignores the filter and shows the measure. What I want is that I can put in the catalogue_no into the selected columns to show the revenue by catalogue_no, but the customer_base by the conformed dimension company and year.

Comment: No. Telling measures their content level is "GT" for non-conformed it works. That's the whole point of the tool since 1997

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. Found also a good source about how to integrate the measures of non-conformed dimensions here. https://www.peakindicators.com/blog/handling-non-conformed-dimensions-a-great-feature-with-obiee-11-1-1-9

Comment: That's just setting the requedlst variable ENABLE_DIMENSIONALITY = TRUE. So basically cheating your way around insufficient RPD design. It was introduced for BICS which shared the initial 11.1.1.9 codebase